# Match cell 1 with range, match cell two with range, cell three value determined by combination of the two ranges (cell 1 and cell 2)

Tags: excel

I have a table drawn in excel that indicates a cell value determined by specific range of 5 values each on the x and y axis.

I have a group of three columns, and for each row, I want to enter a value in one cell (x value) and another value in another cell (y value) and populate a third cell with the xy value determined in the table.

How do I write an =IF( formula to execute this?

So, in very basic terms....x values for example (a, b, c, d, e) and y values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), so the result cell would indicate if x = a and y = 3, result cell = a3?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you have x values in column A starting at A1, Y values in col B starting at B1, in C1 you enter =A1&B1 and copy the formula down as required.